# What’s the difference between the MD 500E and MD 530F helicopters?

Tags: helicopter

What’s the difference between the [MD 500E and MD 530F helicopters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MD_Helicopters_MD_500)? They look almost the same outwardly, and I can’t tell the difference. I would assume parts of the 530F are more modern, but what changed, specifically?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The MD530F is the lift version, designed for hot and high operations. It is fitted with a Rolls-Royce 250-C30 turboshaft engine and has slightly larger diameter rotors and a higher power transmission. A cargo hook kit can be fitted to lift 2,000lb (907kg) external loads.